# Metallic object reflecting dynamic sky instead of hdri

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I created a sky texture using dynamic sky and hdri.
I use lightning from dynamic sky and sky texture from hdri (only texture not its light)  using mix shader and light path(is camera ray)
Now i have a metallic object it is reflecting dynamic sky not hdri. I want it to reflect hdri what i can do ??

Comment: "Is Reflection Ray"?

Comment: no is camera ray. i understand the problem , acutally object is relfecting the light striking on it and the light is coming from dynamic sky not hdri but i want it reflect hdri because its visible in enviroment not dynamic sky what i can do

Comment: I meant, have you tried combining Is Reflection Ray into the mix?

Comment: No its also not working.

Comment: Did you try in Cycles? I am not sure the Sky texture works in Eevee..

Comment: hm... since you want to light up your scene with the sky... all light bouncing should be a reflection so you can't avoid seeing the sky there, unless you do some compositing.

Comment: yes i want to only light up the scene from dynamic sky not it want to present in the enviroment so if the sky is pink object should reflect pink not the dynamic sky

Comment: I believe that's what I illustrated in my answer below. My "dynamic sky" is green and illuminates the scene where as the environment is pink and is showing in the background and on reflections.

Comment: YA BUT USING DIFFUSE RAY ENVIROMENT IS PINK {COLOR FIRST INPUT NODE} AS WEL AS LIGHT IS ALSO PINK MEANS THE COLOR GREEN HAS NO ROLE. I INCREASE STRENGTH OF BACKGROUND NODE OF GREEN COLOR BUT NOTHING CHANGE IN ENVIROMENT

Comment: Please don't use all capitals in your comments. This is considered shouting and rude.

Comment: I added another screenshot showing that the green "sky" strenght is working. Please doublecheck your setup, you must have made a mistake.

Comment: sorry i dont know

Comment: added blend file FYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is Diffuse Ray` might work for you. Here I simulate your HDRI with pink and your Sky with green (the ground has a white diffuse shader).

Here is the blend file: [image]

[image]
[image: show]

Comment: no its not working both in eevee as welll as cycle

Comment: what do you mean? Please explain.

Comment: thanks its working. Thank you very much